# Error: connection not open on send() when trying to connect NodeJs to my Private Geth Node

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, nodejs

hope all are good ?
I have a pb with my FULL NODE i can't connect it with my nodeJs files
I can use my node if file's url is localhost:8546, i'm able to run my script from my server only but i want use my servr with my PC

*From my server folder :*

```
root@x:/home/x/bsc/build/bin
```

*For Geth i run command :*

```
./geth console --config ./config.toml --datadir ./node --cache 8000 --maxpeers 500000000 -- 
rpc.allow-unprotected-txs --txlookuplimit 0 --syncmode full --ws --ws.addr *0.0.0.0**
 ws.port 8546 --wsorigins '*'  --wsapi web3,shh,txpool,debug
```

Geth **is synced**

My server have port open for : **ssh 22 / port 8546 tcp and udp**

I can connect with **PUTTY**

*My files is:*

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const wsProvider = new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider("ws://MyiPNodeAddress:8546")
const web3 = new Web3(wsProvider);


web3.eth.getBlockNumber().then((result) => {
  console.log("Latest Ethereum Block is ",result);
});
```

and return this :

```
Error: connection not open on send()
```

I'm using my mobile phone network connected to my Windows and i'm trying to connect to my geth linux server node then.
I can't connect with my node can someone explain me please why ?

Sincerely Mike

Comment: do a `netstat -pant` as `root` and check if the port is open at the interface you are using to connect. most likely you are listening on loopback address (interface `lo`)

Comment: also there is firewall on linux by default

Comment: i answer you dd

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it will make difference, but make some slight adjusts in the Geth call command:

```
./geth console --config ./config.toml --datadir ./node --cache 8000 --maxpeers 500000000 --rpc.allow-unprotected-txs --txlookuplimit 0 --syncmode full --ws --ws.addr **0.0.0.0** --ws.port 8546 --ws.origins '*'  --ws.api web3,shh,txpool,debug
```

Also, you can install geth in your Windows, if you want, and try to connect with your server to test if it is open to connections:

```
geth attach ws://MyiPNodeAddress:8546
```

Finally ws is not secure, consider to connect to your server through ssh tunnel with the command and alteration in code:

```
ssh -N -L 8546:localhost:8546 <user>@MyiPNodeAddress

const wsProvider = new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider("ws://localhost:8546")
```

Comment: I think i made a mistake if i run script in my server all work good, but i want run script from my .js files

Comment: When do with ssh local when i call : 
web3.eth.getBlockNumber 
return : web3.eth.getBlockNumber()

But i have the pending i put await and don't work

Comment: pending response, looks like there is no connection

Answer (score 0):

I think i made a mistake if i run script in my server all work good, but i want run script **from my .js files from my Visual Studio Code** and actually if do

```
const wsProvider = new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider("ws://MyiPNodeAddress:8546")
```

**it didn't work** but if i run my .js directly from my server the scripts have :

```
const wsProvider = new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider("ws://localhost:8546")
```

and **it always work**

I want run my script with my windows not my server i know this is better to run it with my server but its only to collecting some information not to run finnaly without ssh tunel, i just want to put my ip and work ...